# Install MatroskaProp on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, shell, windows-explorer

To see more information in Windows Explorer property pages and menus about Matroska Video (.mkv) files, similar to what one can see when selecting native Windows media (.avi, .asf, .wmv or even just plain old mpg) files, Matroska links (from http://www.matroska.org/downloads/windows.html) to a download of the MatroskaProp shell extension (http://www.jory.info/serendipity/archives/14-MatroskaProp-2.8-Released.html).

It used to work for me under Windows XP 32-bit.

Now I have Windows 7 x64, and downloaded, installed and ran it.  Configuration and settings page is fine.  But it does not seem to actually register any shell extension.  Nothing is added to Explorer windows, menus or property pages when selecting .mkv or .mks files).  I tried calling the register hook manually using regsvr32.dll, that again invoked the configuration window and let me set all options, and when confirming even said the registration succeeded, but seems to have had no effect.  In the registry I cannot find any traces of the shell extension being installed.

Can this extension be made to work under Windows 7 or x64 systems?  Are there known problems with installing this or other old shell extensions on x64, or on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately (as I am just finding out this week) the 64 bit version of any program (in this case Windows Explorer) cannot use 32 bit dll's (the MatroskaProp shell extension).

The best solution would be to compile a 64 bit version of MatroskaProp and use that, but I'm not entirely sure of all the dependencies and what code changes need to be made to get that to work.

A work around is to open a 32 bit Explorer window and use that instead of a normal 64 bit Explorer window. This is easily done by typing this in the "Run" dialogue box (or the search box in the Start Menu):
"C:\Windows\syswow64\explorer.exe /seperate"
Without the "/seperate" argument it will just open up a regular 64 bit Explorer window, so make sure you type that.

If you want to make a shortcut that will open up a 32 bit Explorer window, I would use
"%windir%\syswow64\explorer.exe /seperate,::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}"
as the path. The bit at the end after "/seperate" basically just says that you want it to open at "My Computer" instead of the defailt "My Documents"